# win32api.GetFileAttributes is thowing 'Access is denied.' error

Tags: python, winapi, msdn

I am trying to get file attributes in python using win32api `GetFileAttributes` method and getting error access is denied.

```
(5, 'GetFileAttributes', 'Access is denied.')
```

MSDN documentation doesn't contain an error section for `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: Are you running the code as admin?

Comment: Ah, and can you post the code you use so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: What file are you trying to access?

Comment: @linusg : as a system user.

Comment: Try to run the code logged in as admin, this is even more important when you're trying to access system files.

Comment: @linusg: I have used simple "win32api.GetFileAttributes(filename)". Actually one of my customer is facing this issue. I don't have enough debug log available now so not aware about type of files.

Comment: What is the program about in general? Are you processing images, videos, music files, textfiles, databases or whatever? What type/extension are you expecting the file to be?

Comment: @linusg My application basically takes backup of files for which i need to use file info for incremental backups. I am getting this error on non OS drive where System Volume Information like folders are excluded. In general what may be cause for this error. I tried to disable permission but couldn't reproduced on my side.

Comment: @linusg: None of that is interesting. It's not like [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944.aspx) would operate differently on an image file than it would for an executable. It doesn't care about file types at all, nor about file extensions. It does care about access rights, though, and it's documented to report errors.

Comment: @IInspectable - That was just to get more information about the OP's program. E.g. almost nobody will try to import a system DLL into a image manipulating program.

Comment: What is your question. You have not asked one.

Answer (score 0):

When the GetFileAttributes function is called, the kernel actualy attempts to open the file with FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES access right. So, if the security descriptor of the file does not grant you that right, you get the access denied error (if some other conditions are not met).

Being an admin/system user on Windows is not the same as being root on Linux. You can do what you want but you need to do some extra work for it. The security model is stil in effect. However, as an administrator (or a higher privileged user) you can use features of the model to get access to everywhere

For example, obtain privileges (SE_BACKUP_NAME, SE_RESTORE_NAME) to act as a backup/restore application which provides you with nearly unlimited access to file system and the registry. Or, you can change security descriptor of the file to grant you necessary access rights (you can do this as a member of the Administrators group, although the integrity levels may impose a problem here – I am not sure of this now).

If you have a directory-listing access to the parent directory, you may try to obtain necessary information about the target file by a directory listing. File attributes are included in the data.